Mahalanobis distance calculation in MatchIt function
I've started to use MatchIt package recently and it's great! I'm also learning a lot by reading the documentation associated with the package. My question is about calculation of Mahalanobis distance. I wanted to replicate the function's output by doing the a simple case (method="nearest", distance="mahalanobis"), and almost always my results match the MatchIt output, but sometimes they don't. I'm copying a screenshot of an example where they don't: "bl", "age" and "gap" are our covariates, and "gr" and "gr_2" denote whether an observation belongs to the treatment group. "MATCH_func" is the MatchIt matching output and "Match_el" is what I calculated (code is copied at the end of the post). The rest of the output is the calculated distance matrix.

As you see, based on MatchIt, the second observation (rn_2) is matched to 8th observation (rn_8), but based on what I calculated it should've been matched to 7th observation, and rn_3 is matched to rn_7, but based on my code should've been matched to rn_8.
Can someone please tell me what is different between my code and what the function does? I suspect it's the way I calculated the pairwise distances, but not sure.
The code:
set.seed(22)

N_pre <- 4
trt_eff <- -0.8
cnt_eff <- -0.3
sd_pp <- 0.5
#######################
df_trt <- data.frame(bl = rnorm(N_pre,mean = 8.8,sd = 1.5),
                     age = rnorm(N_pre,mean = 50,sd = 15),
                     gap = runif(N_pre,min = 3,max = 6 ),gr="trt")

df_trt$val <- df_trt$bl + trt_eff + rnorm(N_pre,mean = 0,sd = sd_pp)

df_cnt <- data.frame(bl = rnorm(N_pre,mean = 8.8,sd = 1.5),
                     age = rnorm(N_pre,mean = 40,sd = 10),
                     gap = runif(N_pre,min = 3,max = 6 ),gr="cnt")

df_cnt$val <- df_cnt$bl + cnt_eff + rnorm(N_pre,mean = 0,sd = sd_pp)

df <- rbind(df_trt,df_cnt)
df$gr_2 <- 0
df$gr_2[which(df$gr == "trt")] <- 1
df_2 <- df

ggplot(df_2) + geom_point(aes(x=bl,y=val))+facet_wrap(~gr)+theme_bw()
########################################
### no caliper
row.names(df_2) <- paste0("rn_",seq(1:nrow(df_2)))
m.out1 <- matchit(gr_2 ~ age + bl + gap,
                  data = df_2, distance = "mahalanobis",
                  method = "nearest",m.order="data",replace = FALSE)
# method = "full")
summary(m.out1, 
        data = df_2)

plot(summary(m.out1),xlim = c(0,2))
### checking mahalanobis ### checking mahalanobis
## closest cnt to each trt based on model
df_2$MATCH_func <- NA
df_2$MATCH_func[which(df_2$gr =="trt")] <- m.out1$match.matrix
df_mnb <- df_2[,c("bl","age","gap")]
dM_0 <- as.data.frame(apply(df_mnb, 1, function(i) mahalanobis(df_mnb, i, cov = cov(df_mnb))))
colnames(dM_0) <- paste0("dist_",seq(1:nrow(dM_0)))
df_2$MATCH_el <- NA
df_2 <- cbind(df_2,dM_0)
jj <- 1
KK <-  nrow(df_2) + 1
for (jj in 1:nrow(df_2)){
  if(df_2$gr[jj]=="cnt") next
  temp <- as.numeric((dM_0[jj,]))
  temp[which(df_2$gr=="trt")] <- 1e5 # so that trt does not match other trt :D
  CC <- TRUE
  while(CC){
    AA <- rank(temp)
    BB <- which(AA==min(AA))
    if(BB %in% KK){
      temp[BB] <- 1e5
    }else{
      KK <- c(KK,BB)
      CC <- FALSE
    }
  }
  df_2$MATCH_el[jj] <- BB
}


The way you computed the Mahalanobis distance is slightly different from how it is calculated in MatchIt. As stated in the documentation here:

$\Sigma$ is the pooled within-group covariance matrix of the
covariates, computed by treatment group-mean centering each covariate
before computing the covariance in the full sample

You supplied cov(df_mnb) to mahalanobis(), which is the raw covariance matrix of the covariates. To compute the pooled covariance matrix, you can either center the covariates at their group means and then compute the raw covariance matrix or compute a weighted average of the within-group covariance matrices where the weights are equal to each group size minus one.
This approach is in line with Rubin (1980), who described Mahalanobis distance matching as it is implemented in MatchIt. You can compute the Mahalanobis distance yourself using MatchIt::mahalanobis_dist(). It is possible to control whether the raw or pooled covariance matrix is used to scaled the distances, and it is possible to supply a distance matrix to matchit(). Note that the mahalanobis() function in base R (the one you used) computes the squared Mahalanobis distance; this doesn't affect the order of units matched but does affect the matching results when using optimal matching.
